# Cambiar de una vista a otra desde una lista con Objetive C?

Tags: ios

He creado una lista personalizada con codigo, necesito que segun  sea la seleccion asi sea la vista que me abra, no se nada de esto, estoy iniciando. Espero puedan darme una ayuda!

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSArray *greekLetters;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.greekLetters = @[@"Himnario",@"Informacion"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.greekLetters count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *SimpleIdentifier = @"SimpleIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:SimpleIdentifier];
}

UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"himnario.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"informacion.png"];


cell.textLabel.text = self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];
//cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
//ESTO ES EL TAMA;O DE LA FUENTE DE TEXTO

if (indexPath.row==0) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Lista de himnos";
    cell.imageView.image= image1;
}
if (indexPath.row==1) {
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Sobre el desarrollador";
    cell.imageView.image= image2;
}
return cell;
}

//ESTO SOLO ES PARA PROBAR CUANDO SELECCIONO ALGO DE ESTA LISTA
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *rowValue = self.greekLetters[indexPath.row];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Ha seleccionado: %@!",rowValue];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item Seleccionado: " message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
//ESTO ES EL ANCHO DE LOS ITEMS
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 50;
}

@end
```

Comment: Podrías poner algo de código, para ver que has estado haciendo

Comment: Dejo el codigo que tengo hasta el momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que en el Storyboard tienes los segue configurados con nombre, cuando seleccionas una fila, para añadir la vista encima de la pila y que sea la que se muestre debes de ejecutar la siguiente línea de código:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nombreSegue" sender:self];
```

De esta forma se mostrará la vista como la tengas configurada en el viewcontroller, por ejemplo, push. Tú ya tienes que tener en cuanta si sería la fila 0, 1, ... n comprobándolo con

```
if ([indexPath row] == 0)
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ventanaFila0" sender:self];
}
```

También tienes una función para hacer lo que necesites antes de que se muestre la nueva vista, la cual ya estaría instanciada.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nombreSegue"])
    {

    }
}
```